# Enhanced alternative to MS Calculator Plus?

Tags: windows, calculator

Microsoft's [Calculator Plus](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21622) usually suits my needs, but occasionally, I need to perform calculations such as gross/net interest rates, etc.

Does someone know of a similar, simple application that supports functions?

Thank you.

Comment: This sort of question is no on topic to Stack Exchange websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use **Google Search**'s built in [graphing calculator](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/12/googles-graphing-calculator.html).

Another similar alternative is [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

For an installed application on Windows, try Speedcrunch speedcrunch.org

Comment: Thanks for the link on Speedcrunch. MS Calculator Plus doesn't even include SQRT :-/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft Mathematics 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/education/ww/products/Pages/mathematics.aspx). Not ideal due to not including financial functions but you can enter your own equations.